# Handle long touch events in ShinobiCharts

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, shinobi

I'm using ShinobiCharts with Xamarin MonoTouch and I would like to allow my PieCharts to allow following features :
- on touch, highlight corresponding legend and show tooltip
- on long touch, reload chart data according to selected value.

SChartDelegate OnToggledSelection function handles the touch event, but is there a way to detect long touch event?